# Only first letter in scanf is being printed out

Tags: c, visual-studio

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int main() {
    char name;
    printf("What is your name:"); // I enter my name..
    scanf_s("%c", &name); // Should grab my name in this case (Brian)
    printf("Hello, %c\n", name); //Should print "Hello, Brian."

    return 0;
}
```

What's wrong? Why is it not storing the whole name and just the first letter?

Comment: You want %s I believe. %c is a single character

Comment: What else do you actually expect when using  a single char output formatting, like `printf("Hello, %c\n", name);`??

Answer (score 0):

Because `name` is only a single `char` and you've used `%c` in `scanf` (and `printf()`).

Looks like what you want is:

```
char name[32]; /* assumes the name is 31 chars or less */
printf("What is your name:"); // I enter my name..
scanf_s("%s", &name); // Should grab my name in this case (Brian)
printf("Hello, %s\n", name); //Should print "Hello, Brian."
```

But since you have flagged the question as C++, then there are better ways of doing it than this!

Comment: So i made the changes, don't know if this is Visual studio or what but whenever the console comes up and asks me to enter my name, i do it and hit enter then Visual studio crashes.. (only after changing %c to %s)

Comment: @Blastfurnace if you mean add the amount of characters, yes i did :/ i don't know why VS is crashing after i input the name and hit enter

Comment: @thatoneaveeno , Use `scanf_s("%s", name, sizeof(name));` and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Missing parameter:

> The `fscanf_s` function is equivalent to `fscanf` except that the `c`, `s`, and `[` conversion specifiers apply to a pair of arguments ... That argument is immediately followed in the argument list by the second argument, which has type `rsize_t` and gives the number of elements in the array pointed to by the first argument of the pair.  C11 §K.3.5.3.2 4

```
// scanf_s("%c", &name);
scanf_s("%c", &name, (rsize_t) 1);
```

This fixes the code's undefined behavior, but still will only save/print 1 `char` of input.

Code should read in a number of `char` as a string.

```
 #define NAME_SIZE 100
 char name[NAME_SIZE];
 scanf_s("%s", &name, (rsize_t) NAME_SIZE);
 printf("Hello, %s\n", name);
```